# how do i Find and then have a callback function

Tags: jquery

I am not sure if my code is correct but I am trying to run some checks on a specific element but my counters are not working - my fields are not hiding.

```
//get all fields, some could be text, text area, checkbox, radio...

$(".my-field").each(function(i) {
var wrapper = this;

//check if the text box has a vaule, this callback here is not working/ correct?

$(wrapper).find("input:text", function() {
                if ($(this).val() != "" || $(this).val().length > 0) {
                    hidden++;
                    $(wrapper).find(".field-content").hide();
                    $(wrapper).addClass("hide");
                } else {
                    visible = visible + 1;
                }
            });
});
```

My Html below is 1 *field* (one div shown below) they are all wrapped inside a div with other fields

```
<div data-field-type="Text" data-field-id="1" class="display-wrapper my-field">
        <div class="field-header">
            <span>name:
                xyz</span> | <span>
                    text field</span>
        </div>
        <div class="field-content">
            <div class="editor-label">
                <p class="clear">
                    some description...</p>
            </div>

<div class="editor-field">
    <input type="text" value="iojhiojio" name="1" maxlength="100" id="field-1" class="field-bigtext">
</div>
            <br>
        </div>
        <div style="display: none;" class="field-error-wrapper">

        </div>
    </div>
```

My Question, is this possible with jquery:

```
$(wrapper).find("input:text", function() {
.. some code
});
```

Comment: wrapper is also not defined in the given code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're probably looking for `.each()`, in order to do something to each element.

```
$(wrapper).find("input:text").each(function() {
    if ($(this).val() != "" || $(this).val().length > 0) {
        hidden++;
        $(wrapper).find(".field-content").hide();
        $(wrapper).addClass("hide");
    } 
    else {
        visible++;
    }
});
```

`.find()` only does one thing: find objects inside the element you're running it on which matches a given selector/object.

Edit: having read your comment, you said you only want to do something to a single element. So just store what you get in `.find()` in a variable, and do stuff with it.

```
var inputElem = $(wrapper).find('input:text');
if (inputElem.val() != "" || inputElem.val().length > 0) {
    hidden++;
    $(wrapper).find('.field-content').hide();
    $(wrapper).addClass("hide");
} 
else {
    visible++;
}
```

Comment: No- i only have one element inside a wrapper when it is a text box, your code would be ok for radio boxes, because I have many elements inside my wrapper and I need to check all of them

Comment: How do I run a function of find? or after find? as there is only ever 1 element

Comment: I updated my answer for that scenario. It'll do the same thing though, but it may be marginally faster.

Comment: Thanks - it seems I cannot use find without storing the object inside a var

Comment: Need to define hidden and visible variable. Hide() and addClass('hide') does the same. And This code is working well

Comment: @Umesh: addClass("hide") - this is for my css, i need to add some styling that is already defined. the 2 variables - could be declared outside this method - but to be honest they are not relevant so I should have removed from the code. My question was more to do with the 'find()' method - thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

Just add each.

```
//get all fields, some could be text, text area, checkbox, radio...
$(".my-field").each(function (i) {
    var wrapper = this;
    //check if the text box has a vaule, this callback here is not working/ correct?
    $(wrapper).find("input:text").each(function () {
        if($(this).val() != "" || $(this).val().length > 0) {
            hidden++;
            $(wrapper).find(".field-content").hide();
            $(wrapper).addClass("hide");
        } else {
            visible = visible + 1;
        }
    });
});
```